# Allow post type to optionally return title field

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, api-v2.1

Currently, it's possible to get the `title` field from the [`question`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) type returned by `/questions/{ids}` and from the [`answer` type](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/answer) returned by `/answers/{ids}`, using the appropriate filters.

Unfortunately, the [`post` type](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/post) doesn't expose this field, so if you're interested in the post title for a list of question and answer IDs (useful for display purposes), you're stuck making two separate requests instead of using the otherwise convenient `/posts/{ids}` route.

Could the `post` type be updated to return the `title` field when supplied an appropriate filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [added in version 2.2](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/change-log), hooray!